# Lens Space and Bipyramid homeomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, general-topology

Define lens Space $L(p,q)$ as the orbit space of the action of $Z_p$ on $S^3$ (viewed as a sphere in $\Bbb C^2$).
Consider $p$, $q$ coprime 
Define action of a generator $g$ as $g\cdot(z,w)=(ze^{2\pi i/p},we^{2\pi iq/p})$
This defines the whole action.
Now consider a regular $p$-gon and a North Pole and South Pole above and below the centre of gravity.
Complete the bipyramid and for each triangle with two adjacent vertex and North Pole identify another triangle as follows---
Identify $a_i$ to $a_{i+q}$, $a_{i+1}$ to $a_{i+q+1}$ and North Pole to South Pole.(the above indices are in mod p)
Show that this identification space is homeomorphic to $L(p,q)$.

Comment: Did you try putting a CW structure on the lens space? Perhaps putting one on the sphere compatible with the group action?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you please elaborate?